# Center Links and Button in Navbar

Tags: html, css

I want to horizontally center the links and the button, but frankly I have no idea how to do it. I would really appreciate your help!

I already tried `text-align: center;` but that doesn't work.

```
<nav>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <div>
    <button>Products</button>
    <div>
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#">About</a>
</nav>
```

```
nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

nav a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav div {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav div button {
  line-height: inherit;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 1em;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

nav a:hover, nav div button:hover {
  background-color: #222;
}

nav div div {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #eee;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
}

nav div div a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

nav div div a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

nav div:hover > div {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plz try this code..

**css**

```
nav {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex; *for cross browser*
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center; *for cross browser*
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code.

```css
nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  display: -webkit-flex; 
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
}

nav a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav div {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav div button {
  line-height: inherit;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 1em;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

nav a:hover, nav div button:hover {
  background-color: #222;
}

nav div div {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #eee;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
}

nav div div a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

nav div div a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

nav div:hover > div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="text-center">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <div>
    <button>Products</button>
    <div>
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#">About</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

nav a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav div {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav div button {
  line-height: inherit;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 1em;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

nav a:hover, nav div button:hover {
  background-color: #222;
}

nav div div {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #eee;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
}

nav div div a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

nav div div a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

nav div:hover > div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav style="justify-content:center; display:flex; flex-flow:wrap row;">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <div>
    <button>Products</button>
    <div>
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#">About</a>
</nav>
```

I have changed the code and have applied [flex property](https://www.web4college.com/css-play/demo-flex.php). Now the items will always be at the center.